# Unresponsive Leaflet's addLayersControl()

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to produce a map so that I can choose which groups of data points to display. It does work until I try to 'improve' my legend, i.e. by including the different types of markers in it.

Right now, my points are displayed correctly, the legend also displays correctly, but when I uncheck one of the groups, nothing happens. Any idea how to fix this? I've spent a couple of hours on it but can't figure it out.

Cheers!

Here is my code:

```
library("leaflet")

df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 type = c("Always", "Often", "Never"),
                 city = c("Paris", "Marseille", "Bordeaux"),
                 lat = c(48.9, 43.3, 44.8),
                 long = c(2.3, 5.4, -0.6))

#Create list of icons
IconSet <- awesomeIconList(
  "Always"   = makeAwesomeIcon(icon = "map-marker", markerColor = "green", library = "glyphicon"),
  "Often"   = makeAwesomeIcon(icon = "map-marker", markerColor = "blue", library = "glyphicon"),
  "Never" = makeAwesomeIcon(icon = "map-marker", markerColor = "red", library = "glyphicon"))

#Create groups
groups <- c("Always" <- "<div style='position: relative; display: inline-block' class='awesome-marker-icon-green awesome-marker'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker icon-white '></i></div>Always displayed",
            "Often" <- "<div style='position: relative; display: inline-block' class='awesome-marker-icon-blue awesome-marker'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker icon-white '></i></div>Often displayed",
            "Never" <- "<div style='position: relative; display: inline-block' class='awesome-marker-icon-red awesome-marker'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker icon-white '></i></div>Never displayed")

#Create map
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 5, maxZoom = 9)) %>% 
  setView(lng = 2.4, lat = 46.5, zoom = 5) %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(icon = ~IconSet[type],
                    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(freezeAtZoom = 9),
                    data = df, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
                    group = ~groups[type]) %>% 
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = groups, options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE), position = "topleft")
m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution... and it was a pretty silly issue.

Unlike with regular markers, `data =` must apparently not be defined in `addAwesomeMarkers()` but rather in `leaflet()`...

Last bit of working code becomes:

```
m <- leaflet(data = df) %>% 
addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 5, maxZoom = 9)) %>% 
setView(lng = 2.4, lat = 46.5, zoom = 5) %>% 
addAwesomeMarkers(icon = ~IconSet[type], group = ~groups[type]) %>% 
addLayersControl(overlayGroups = groups, options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE), position = "topleft")
```

Comment: I have run into a similar problem, and have also tried to reproduce your code, but addLayersControl() remains unresponsive. Do we know whether the package has been changed since 2019?!